# partition size in centos 7 for mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning, centos7, whmcs

I want to have a server as a database server with mysql. I want implement it on centos 7, but I have a problem about partition configuration in centos.
I want install only mysql on this server and I want know, how much should be assigned space to below directory in centos 7:
root
var
home
usr
tmp
And at finally, which file system is good for above partitions: xfs or ext4?
Note: I have run this scenario on VMware/esxi and I have 30 GB space and 2 GB RAM for this VM. And I want use this database/mysql for WHMCS.

Comment: Use the defaults.  30GB+2GB is tiny these days.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you guide me about it, I don't want use default setting. I can increase the storage, but I think 30Gb is good for WHMCS. I want to have on this server only MySQL for WHMCS. If I think mistake please help me.

Comment: It does not really matter where you put mysql -- I would just let it put itself in the default place.  But be sure that partition is big enough for your eventual data size.  The main tunable is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` which needs to be, say, 200M or less.